# Adding AutoComplete to an Infragisitcs UltraDateTimeEditor control

Tags: .net, winforms, infragistics

I'm attempting to modify an Infragisitcs UltraDateTimeEditor control so that the current year and a default time are inserted when the user only enters values for the month and day.

The control has an AutoFillDate property, however setting this to "year" seems to overwrite user input entirely. Also changing the InvalidTextBehavior doesn't seem to help since the control starts out empty.

What event(s) would I need to modify in order get the fill-in data to populate before the validation reverts to an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Event to handle for this is "BeforeExitEditMode."  I was able to inspect and modify the user input before the validators fired.